# Como tornar invisivel uma activity usando código em android?

Tags: android

Exempo: Quero iniciar uma activity no final do boot do android, mas não quero que ela seja mostrada neste momento (é um serviço). No entanto, ao clicar no ícone da aplicação, ela deverá ser mostrada normalmente. Só quero que seja invisível no hora do boot.

Exemplo de uso: Tenho um app e quero inicia-lo no boot do android, mas esta opção tem que ser escolhida pelo usuário (Isto eu já resolví).

Eu fiz assim: Usei o Receiver para chamar uma outra activity no boot, independente se usuário ter optado ou não. Então esta activity lê o arquivo de configuração e verifica a opçao do usuário. Se NÃO é para iniciar, então eu fecho esta activity (com finish() ). Senão, lanço meu app. Mas meu app já abre a janela e fica aberto, queria inicia-lo tipo, "minimizado" do windows.. ou aculto.

Alguém teria uma solução?

Comment: Bem vindo ao SOpt. O que você já tentou?

Comment: A pergunta está um pouco confusa. Não consigo distinguir o que você já conseguiu fazer do que não conseguiu e não tenho a certeza do que quer fazer.